# SharePoint Online Powershell get content of an file

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, pnp-powershell, xml, file

I would like to read the content of XML files in SharePoint Online. I would like to check if the XML file contains some text. I already tried something like this but it is not working:

```
Connect-PnPOnline https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/teams/SomeSiteCollection
$fileRelativeURL = "/SomeDocumentLibrary/test.xml"
$file = Get-PnPFile -Url $fileRelativeURL -AsListItem
$stream = $file.OpenBinaryStream()
```

But the stream is empty and has no value.

[image]

How to get the content of a file in PowerShell and SharePoint Online?

Comment: Try [this](https://prairiedeveloper.com/2018/02/read-xml-data-files-stored-sharepoint-library/) and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hi @GaneshSanap, thank you. This article is SharePoint on prem. I would like to run a powershell script to SharePoint Online.

Comment: You can get the XML content as a string using PnP PowerShell in SP Online. check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the XML file content as a string in a variable, use below code:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName -UseWebLogin
$fileRelativeURL = "/sites/SiteName/Shared Documents/test.xml"
$file = Get-PnPFile -Url $fileRelativeURL -AsString
```

**Documentation**: [Get-PnPFile - Examples](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpfile#examples)

Then you can check if the text is present in XML file string or not using:

```
$textToFind = "SomeTextFromFile"
$index = $file.indexOf($textToFind)
```

If `$index` is equal to `-1` then the substring (`$textToFind`) is not found in XML file content **Else** it is found.

Comment: This works great! Thank you. I love pnp powershell

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.